# Actions on Google - can your response to the user send text or pictures to the Google Home app?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, actions-on-google

Specifically, is there an equivalent of [the capability described here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/providing-home-cards-for-the-amazon-alexa-app) that exists in Alexa Skills Kit where you can send a Card in your Skill's response?

Comment: Yes you can :) 
You have the displayText, you can find the details [here](https://docs.api.ai/docs/webhook#section-format-of-response-from-the-service)
(Made a comment and not a response because I'm not 100% sure this is what you are looking for, let me know)

Comment: Hi Lorena, thanks. Are you sure the api.ai 'displayText' field can be utilized via Actions on Google so that it shows up as a Card on the Google Home app? Got an example of how?

Comment: There is an example over there (About Obama) 
`Body:
{
"speech": "Barack Hussein Obama II is the 44th and current President of the United States.",
"displayText": "Barack Hussein Ob...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now available.

Reference documentation: https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/nodejs/RichResponse

Example:
https://developers.google.com/actions/apiai/tutorials/google-facts

Answer (score 1):

As of 2017/04 I am quite sure there is no possibility to send a card.

There is no such functionality indicated in [Google Action Documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/conversation) and on API.AI, the [Card feature](https://docs.api.ai/docs/rich-messages#card) is not available.

With displayText you can differentiate between spoken and, well, displayed Text, but this is not really a so called Rich Message, where you can add Images, Button, Titles etc.

However, I am 100% positive that this feature will be added soon.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Alexa supports displaying a card in the Alexa app as part of its response. How you do that depends on which Alexa framework or SDK you are using, but its not difficult at all.
For example, I'm using the alexa-app framework, and I would just add something like this:

```js
response.card({
  type: "Standard",
  title: "My Cool Card", // this is not required for type Simple or Standard 
  text: "Your ride is on the way to 123 Main Street!\nEstimated cost for this ride: $25",
  image: { // image is optional 
    smallImageUrl: "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-small.png", // required 
    largeImageUrl: "https://carfu.com/resources/card-images/race-car-large.png"
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm asking for how to do the same thing using Actions on Google - is there _**an equivalent**_ of the ASK capability.